# How do you find a missing coefficient in the equation of a plane if you know that it is perpendicular to another plane?

Tags: vectors

Equation of one plane is 3x + 4y - 5z = 60
Equation of another plane is 4x + 2y + cz = 0

My thought was to find the normal vector of the first plane.  Since I know it is perpendicular to the normal vector of the 2nd plane, I thought I could use dot products, but I was unsure how to find the normal vector of the 2nd plane.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you can find normal to one plane, use the same technique to find normal to another

Answer (score 1):

Your idea works just fine. Just think about how we can get the normal vector of a plane from its equation, and take the dot product of both of them, set it to $0$, and then solve for $c$ (you'll end up with a linear equation).